# Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I was trying to add Firebase to my project in Android Studio, but I can't get rid of one error: "Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0; Searched in the following locations..."

I've followed the instructions found here:

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries
```

I've imported my google project, gave the name and SHA-1 key for the project, downloaded the config file... then I've entered the Android Studio terminal and enter the following command: "move %google-services.json location% /app" and also modify the gradle.build files:

The gradle.build(project) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the build.gradle(app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.francydarkcool.maps"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services'
```

PS. Both Google Play Services and Google Repository are installed and up to date.

Comment: Hello, as this is a simple typo, please delete the question.

Comment: i'm up voting your question because this solved my problem anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
    classpath 'com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Should be "gms" instead of "gsm":

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: That is probably the one; I didn't notice that! Good eye.

Comment: thks, I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this by renaming the line shown below:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' //rename this

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
     jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As pointed out by another answer above, there is a typo. Let me know how it goes?

Good luck!

Comment: I've got rid of that error, but now I have another one "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' > [string/google_app_id]" -> "Error: Duplicate resources"

Comment: So, I see that you have added the whole google-play-services library and then again added the maps; you see, there is already map support in the google-play-services library and I don't think you need to have both. Try removing one (if you need more than map features, you can remove the map-services line)

Comment: I've removed the line <string name="google_app_id">...</string> from the strings.xml file and it worked ;)